# ¿Cómo detectar que mes es y que me seleccione el primer dia de dicho mes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo este Query y quiero saber  como puedo hacer que la variable @From_date detecte que mes es y me de resultado el primer dia del mes en un formato INT ejem. es Mayo 21 me regresaria algo como 20200301

```
DECLARE @date_end      INT
DECLARE @From_date     INT
DECLARE @ID            INT
DECLARE @SQL           NVARCHAR(MAX)
       SET @From_date = ???
       SET @date_end   = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)) --manage end date
       SET @ID = 184477 --change ident on demand
EXEC [TemporlTable1] @date_start, @DATE, @ID
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Now        DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @From_date  INT

SET @From_date  = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Now - DAY(@Now) + 1, 112))

SELECT @From_date
```

Tomamos la fecha de hoy y le restamos la cantidad de días más 1, eso nos da el primer día del mes, luego el metódo actual para llevar todo a un valor entero.

Answer (score 1):

Esto te devolverá siempre el primer dia del mes actual:

```
select  dateadd(MM, datediff(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) as 'Primer Dia del Mes Actual';

select convert(varchar(20), dateadd(MM, datediff(MM, 0, getdate()), 0), 112) as 'Primer Dia del Mes Actual (varchar)';

select convert(int, convert(varchar(20), dateadd(MM, datediff(MM, 0, getdate()), 0), 112)) as 'Primer Dia del Mes Actual (int)';
```

Comment: si, pero lo necesito aun en formato yyyymmdd INT Ejemp. 20200311

Comment: Es cuestion de convertirlo, te agregue como esa fecha a varchar y también a Int